# Linkedin Authentication Issue - Not enough permissions to access: GET /people/~:

Tags: linkedin-api

I am using social authentication in my application. Using below Linked In api

1.

```
  https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me/~:(id,firstName,lastName)
```

Getting error:

> {"serviceErrorCode":0,"message":"Resource me does not
>   exist","status":404}

2.

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v2/people/~:(id,email-address,first-name,last-name,headline,industry,public-profile-url,picture-url,summary,site-standard-profile-request,api-standard-profile-request,location,distance,num-connections,num-connections-capped,specialties,proposal-comments,associations,honors,interests,positions,skills,educations,num-recommenders,recommendations-received,phone-numbers,im-accounts,twitter-accounts,date-of-birth,main-address,member-url-resources,certifications,publications,courses,languages)?oauth2_access_token=
```

Getting error:

> Not enough permissions to access: GET /people/~:

Answer (score 1):

For the first one try using:

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me?projection=(id,firstName,lastName)
```

and for the second one, you might want to check if you have correct permissions on your linkedIn app. You might need `r_basicprofile, r_emailaddress, w_member_social`.

For more details on permissions see : 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/authentication/permissions?context=linkedin/context